# How to interpret the output of `mount` on Catalina

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, filesystem, mount

When I run `mount` on my system, it lists the following

```
/dev/disk1s5 on / (apfs, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

What do each of these devices do? How do they fit together? A link to a decent reference would suffice.

Also, when I cross-reference this list with the output from `$ df -h`, I saw something that boggles my basic understanding of how mounting works: The total amount of disk space apportioned  exceeds my HD capacity (500GB). How is this so?

```
Filesystem                                                                                             Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5                                                                                          466Gi   10Gi  179Gi     6%  484398 4881968482    0%   /
devfs                                                                                                 339Ki  339Ki    0Bi   100%    1174          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s1                                                                                          466Gi  273Gi  179Gi    61% 3701532 4878751348    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4                                                                                          466Gi  3.0Gi  179Gi     2%       4 4882452876    0%   /private/var/vm
map auto_home                                                                                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```